# COUNTROWS and ALL - Keeping row headers using only DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm looking for a solution **TO GET THE TABLE 1 AS RESULT**.

[example tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qze0a.png)

The problem is that when I apply a month filter by the slicer, the result is the table 2.

**Please, I need a solution by using DAX. I know that I can use Interactions Editor.**

Below, the DAX I'm using.

Addtionality, there is a relationship between these two table 1:* dCalendar > fChurnReason.

The row headers are from dCalendar.

```
Countrows = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS(fChurnReason),
    VALUES(dCalendar[Month]),
    ALL(dCalendar)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in DAX that you can do to show different rows of the same table that is used by a slicer. As an example, create a measure like this:

```
measureTest = 1
```

And the other months will simply no show because of the above.

You have two options:

1. Switch off slicer interaction to that visual - see [Control which page visuals are affected by slicers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/visuals/power-bi-visualization-slicers?tabs=powerbi-desktop#control-which-page-visuals-are-affected-by-slicers)
2. Use a different table for the visual than the slicer. Eg `fChurnReason[Month]` if that exists.